# How to find shortest word in a java string without using arrays?

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to use the same format of this code which I followed through a tutorial. It will print the longest word as well as the length of the longest word. The tutor told me that to find the shortest word I have to flip the if statement to be less than ('<') instead of greater than... however, after I enter any string, when I run the program it returns:

"Shortest Word: "", length: 0"

I'm not sure how to fix this so it looks for an actual word and not an empty character.. I'd like to follow the same logic here without using arrays as well.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a phrase: ");
String phrase = in.nextLine();


String w = "";
String lw = "";       
int l;
char ch;


phrase = phrase + " ";
l = phrase.length();
int i;
for (i=0; i < l; i++) {
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    if(ch != ' ') {
        w = w + ch;
    } else {
        if(w.length() > lw.length()) {
            lw = w;
        }
        w = "";
    }
}

System.out.println("Longest Word: \"" + lw + "\", length: "+ lw.length());
```

Comment: the code you have shown can't possibly return the output you show.

Comment: I forgot to add, the user inputs any phrase they choose to

Comment: be that as it may, the code you've shown can not produce "Shortest Word: "", length: 0" as output

Comment: First, store `lw.length()` in a variable instead of always calculating it. Then you have a check `w.length() > lwLength` instead. If you filp it, that is a good first step — but in order for it to work, whereas longest word needs to start short and get longer as you find better candidates, shortest word needs to start _long_ and get cut _shorter_. Start with `lwLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I agree with @Stultuske. How can `System.out.println("Longest Word: \"" + lw + "\", length: "+ lw.length());` suddenly create the output of `"Shortest Word: "", length: 0"`?

Comment: By "without arrays" do you mean not using `split(...)` and methods like that?

Comment: @Stultuske I believe the OP posted the original code that produces the longest word, and asks how to change that code in order to obtain the shortest word. The output the OP printed refers to the outcome after changing the > to < in the if statement, which is not sufficient.

Comment: yes @ Eran that is right

Comment: Note that this logic could be modify to check the length between "spaces" and to "substring" the shortest length. This would requires the use of "indexOf" and "substring" instead of accessing the character yourself. The logic and the complexity would be the same, but the could would be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to do is change

```
if(w.length() > lw.length())
```

to

```
if(w.length() < lw.length())
```

However, that's not enough, since `lw` in initialized to an empty `String`, so the condition will always be `false` (`w.length()` will never be < 0).

Therefore you also have to check whether `lw` is still empty:

```
if(w.length() < lw.length() || lw.isEmpty ()) {
    lw = w;
}
```

The full code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a phrase: ");
String phrase = in.nextLine();

String w = "";
String lw = "";       
int l;
char ch;

phrase = phrase + " ";
l = phrase.length();
int i;
for (i=0; i < l; i++) {
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    if(ch != ' ') {
        w = w + ch;
    } else {
        if(w.length() < lw.length() || lw.isEmpty ()) {
            lw = w;
        }
        w = "";
    }
}

System.out.println("Shortest Word: \"" + lw + "\", length: "+ lw.length());
```

Comment: This is excellent, I really appreciate this tip.. In addition if two or more words are the same length, how would I make the latter (last) shortest word print instead of the first

Comment: @gingerhaus38 you can do that by changing `<` to `<=`

Comment: Got it, I made a mistake earlier, now for some reason the code still produces  "" as the shortest character although I specifically changed this how I should

Comment: @gingerhaus38 I tried the code I posted and it works fine.